# Renaming value of column PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

i have a dataset like this

| Contract ID | Detailed Name | Finale Naiming |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contract 1 | 1.1 | Contract 1 (1.1, 1.2) |
| Contract 1 | 1.1 | Contract 1 (1.1, 1.2) |
| Contract 1 | 1.2 | Contract 1 (1.1, 1.2) |
| Contract 2 | 1.1 | Contract 2 (1.1) |
| Contract 3 | 1.1 | Contract 3 (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4) |
| Contract 3 | 1.2 | Contract 3 (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4) |
| Contract 3 | 1.3 | Contract 3 (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4) |
| Contract 3 | 1.4 | Contract 3 (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4) |

In the "Contract ID" column I have the code of each contract, in the "Detailed Name" column the contract paragraphs.
My goal is to create the "Final Naiming" column in which I report the contract ID with the paragraphs of each contract concatenated and in brackets.

I don't know how to set the code.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Finale Naiming = 
'Table'[Contract ID] & " (" &
CALCULATE( CONCATENATEX(VALUES('Table'[Detailed Name]), 'Table'[Detailed Name], ","), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Contract ID]))
& ")"
```